# Get user to input only numbers or A-Z?

Tags: java

```
static void a1()
{

   int choice;
   Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("Enter Part#: ");
   pa[count] = sc1.nextLine();

   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("Enter Make: ");
   ma[count] = sc1.nextLine();

   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("Enter description: ");
   so[count] = sc1.nextLine();

   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("Enter price: ");
   pr[count] = sc1.nextLine();

   ++count; 

 }
```

How do I get the user to input either only numbers or letters from A-Z?

Comment: You can adapt this answer to your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13115310/2308683

Comment: `System.out.println("Please enter only numbers or letters from A-Z");`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each section in a while loop. That repeats asking the user for input until they enter valid information.

```
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter Part#: ");
    pa[count] = sc1.nextLine();
}
while(checkAlpha(pa[count]) == false);
```

Then create a function to check each value in the string for valid characters.

```
public static boolean checkAlpha(String phrase)
{
    char[] tempChars = phrase.toCharArray();
    for(char c : tempChars)
    {
        if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You also could do this using regex by changing the while check to:

```
while(!pa[count].matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help :)

I used regex and it worked! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Pattern` class to build a Matcher, you should be able to just use the pattern `[^\\p{Alnum}]` and then call the `find()` method to look for any matching instance of the pattern.