# Asks user to enter values until an integer is entered

Tags: java

I am a noob in programming.
I wanted to write code for a prog which asks user to enter value until an integer is entered.

```
public class JavaApplication34 {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int flag = 0;
        while(flag == 0) {
            int x = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");

            try {
                x = sc.nextInt();
                flag = 1;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error");        
            }

            System.out.println("Value "+ x);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the code is correct and it should ask me to enter the value again if i have entered anything other than an integer.
But when i run it , and say i enter xyz
it iterates infinite time without asking me to enter the value.

```
test run :
Enter an integer
xyz
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
Enter an integer
error
Value 0
```

Comment: In a catch block such as your ``catch(Exception e){``, the ``e`` holds valuable information about what happened. Use ``e.printStackTrace()`` to find out more.

Comment: Your `flag` is very sad because it wants to be boolean.

Comment: why??? please help

Comment: @MridulMittal read the answer posted by T.J. Crowder

Answer (score 5):

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception.

Hence `sc.nextInt()` reads the same token again and throws the same exception again.

```
...
...
...
catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println("error");
     sc.next(); // <---- insert this to consume the invalid token
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the error case, you need to clear out the string you've entered (for instance, via [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)). Since it couldn't be returned by `nextInt`, it's still pending in the scanner. You also want to move your line outputting the value *into* the `try`, since you don't want to do it when you have an error.

Something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int flag = 0;
    while(flag == 0)
    {
        int x = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        try
        {
            x = sc.nextInt();
            flag = 1;
            System.out.println("Value "+ x);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("error");
            if (sc.hasNextLine()) { // Probably unnecessary
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Java has `boolean`, there's no need to use `int` for flags. So:

```
boolean flag = false;
```

and

```
while (!flag) {
```

and

```
flag = true; // When you get a value
```

Comment: can you help ??

Comment: @MridulMittal: That **is** help.

Comment: If you will not try to solve them on your own even after knowing the error, You will remain a **NOOB**.

Comment: @MridulMittal: The best way, by far, to become a non-n00b is to work things through. But I've added an example of what you might do above.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your logic as shown below :

```
    int flag = 0;
    int x = 0;
    String str="";
    while (flag == 0) {         
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        try {
            str = sc.next();
            x = Integer.parseInt(str);
            flag = 1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Value " + str);
        }           
    }
```

Here we have first read the input from Scanner and then we are trying to parse it as int, if the input is not an integer value then it will throw exception. In case of exception we are printing what user has enter. When user enters an integer then it will parsed successfully and value of flag will update to 1 and it will cause loop to exit.

Answer (score 0):

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115266/how-to-insist-that-a-users-input-is-an-inthttp://) question might help you

It makes use of Scanners `.hasNextInt()` function!